# Horizontal Bar Chart direction

Tags: kotlin, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

Is it possible to create Horizontal Bar Chart and draw bars from right to left? Just make mirror reflection. I can't use **rotate** in my xml because label also will be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the render from HorizontalBarChartRenderer to your customed render, and override function :protected void drawDataSet(Canvas c, IBarDataSet dataSet, int index);
add these lines after " // initialize the buffer"

```
BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[index];
buffer.setPhases(phaseX, phaseY);
buffer.setDataSet(index);
buffer.setInverted(mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency()));
buffer.setBarWidth(mChart.getBarData().getBarWidth());

buffer.feed(dataSet);

trans.pointValuesToPixel(buffer.buffer);

final boolean isSingleColor = dataSet.getColors().size() == 1;

if (isSingleColor) {
    mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());
}

for (int j = 0; j < buffer.size(); j += 4) {

    if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsTop(buffer.buffer[j + 3]))
        break;

    if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsBottom(buffer.buffer[j + 1]))
        continue;

    if (!isSingleColor) {
        // Set the color for the currently drawn value. If the index
        // is out of bounds, reuse colors.
        mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j / 4));
    }

    // NEWLY ADDED CODE BELOW
    float left = buffer.buffer[j];
    float right = buffer.buffer[j + 2];
    float midLine = (mViewPortHandler.contentLeft() + mViewPortHandler.contentRight()) / 2;
    buffer.buffer[j] = midLine + (midLine - right);
    buffer.buffer[j + 2] = midLine + (midLine - left);
```

look like this:
[image]